# Deleting file if it crashes my app

Tags: java, error-handling, crash, resume, traversal

Does anyone know how to delete a file if it crashes my app on the NEXT run? Eg. My app browses through an array of pictures. One of them crashes my system and on my next run i want it to delete that error-producing picture and continue browsing through the array of pictures. I am way out of ideas on this.

Comment: Does you _app_ crash or the whole phone?

Answer (score 2):

```
try{
    //working with the file
   }catch(Exception e){
   //delete file
   }
```

Comment: This is probably the correct approach *unless* the "crashes my app" is actually a full-on JVM crash. In that case the solutions by MByD or cularis are the way to go.

Comment: Maybe there are other reasons which may crash your application.I think if it is for the file operation then you can catch it by IOException and can delete it

Comment: i can't use any try{}catch{} methods to solve this in case a full JVM crash happens, i need to have a solution ready

Answer (score 2):

Write a log with every accessed image and a line that indicates the normal end of your processing. If the last line in the log is not your end-of-processing line, it's your corrupt file.

Answer (score 2):

Each time, before you access to a file, save it in shared preferences (under a certain key), after successful access delete it from the shared preferences. When you start your activity check if there is a file name under that key, and if so - delete it.

**Edit:**

The idea is to "log" any attempt to access a file, and if the access succeeds than remove this log. if you start your app and see that there are remains from last time, you understand that an error occurred last time you attempted to access this file.

Comment: i don't quite understand this. can you please elaborate further thanks

Comment: i see, let me try this out =)